# IBM Mobilefirst foundation studio in Eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new in IBM Mobilefirst. Today I have downloaded Eclipse Neon and tried to add IBM Mobilefirst studio plug in from Eclipse Marketplace.

But marketplace does not show any result for IBM Mobilefirst studio.

Please suggest how can I get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's there:

[image]

However please note that MobileFirst Studio v8.0 is unlike past releases.
In past releases you would use it to create Hybrid apps. In v8.0, you only use the Studio plug-in if you want to create an IDE-like environment in Eclipse for **Cordova application development**.

In v8.0, you create standard Cordova applications. The MobileFirst SDK is not a standard Cordova plug-in.

The Studio plug-in is there as a means to externalize CLI commands such as: register and preview for apps, which you now do via CLI commands...

Learn more here:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/product-overview/release-notes/whats-new/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/

If you're looking for an older release of MobileFirst Studio, you can find it here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/#downloadPreviousReleases