# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Neon plugin

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-neon

I tried your answer for the latest version of neon [IBM Mobilefirst foundation studio in Eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783805/ibm-mobilefirst-foundation-studio-in-eclipse-neon-1-release-4-6-1/41612439#41612439) , but was unable to find the 8.0.0 plugin

Its not listed on the marketplace http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/%2522mobilefirst%2522

Also, when I use the eclipse marketplace from the help menu, I cannot see it either. how do I install it? Please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that support is currently not available for Eclipse Neon.

Please downgrade to Eclipse Mars, where searching for "mobilefirst" in the Eclipse Marketplace section will find the MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 plug-in for installation.